# Assembly- preserving register values?

Tags: assembly, x86, printf

I am having some trouble with, what I believe to be, using printf inside of a function that I have created in assembly.  The function I made is:

```
printnstars:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl 4(%esp), %ebx

starloop:
    cmpl %ebx, %edi
    je exitloop
    incl %edi
    pushl $star
    call printf
    addl $4, %esp
    jmp starloop

exitloop:
    ret
```

The function takes in a number as a parameter, which I moved to %ebx, and prints that number of "*"s using:

```
star:
    .asciz "*"
```

The function does what it is supposed to do, but I run into problems when I try to do something like this:

```
    pushl (%ecx)
    call printnstars
    pushl (%ecx)
    call printnstars
```

Where (%ecx) is 2.  If I only do one call, it behaves as expected and prints 2 stars, but when I call it again it prints infinite stars.  It's quite obvious that %ecx must have gotten messed with inside of printf because I didn't use that register in anything I created.  What do I do to make sure that (%ecx) will remain constant through multiple calls to printnstars?

Also it may be useful to note that this is used inside of a function that is printing a histogram with stars on each line referring to the number of time a number occurs.  I have all of the frequency values based around %ecx, so that is why I am using (%ecx).

Comment: Jack, please stop defacing your question. I'm not going to delete this, because it's a good question with a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I do to make sure that (%ecx) will remain constant through multiple calls to printnstars?

You save the register value in a local variable on the stack.

Also, remember that `printf()` takes a variable number of parameters and since it doesn't know beforehand how many of them there are and of what type, it doesn't remove the on-stack parameters and removing them from the stack (by adjusting `esp`) becomes the caller's responsibility.

Comment: Alright so do I add pushl %ecx before the first call and then a popl %ecx before the second call?  Also I did do addl $4, %esp after the printf call so didn't I do that correctly...?

Comment: You could push it twice and then call the function twice as well. How about that? And take care of printf's on-stack params.

Comment: Doesn't addl $4 %esp take care of that?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. It probably does.

Comment: Alright and I did two pushes and then called it twice and that seemed to work :) Thanks.